# os.getenv or os.environ don't reach variables in .env file

Tags: python, python-os

In my directory, I have a .env file with:

```
HOST="url_to_host"
```

I also have my `script.py`, where:

```
import os
os.environ["HOST"]
```

If I run the script in Vscode debug mode, everything works. However, in normal mode, I get a key error, or if I use `os.getenv("HOST")` I get `NoneType`.

Comment: In normal operation, `.env` files are ignored.  If you want to _always_ use the `.env` file, then you need special code to read the file and import its contents into your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my script:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load your enviroment variables with **load_dotenv()** before trying to get them

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()
os.getenv("HOST")
```